# Execute installer package if not installed from Wizard Installer MSI (Winform, VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, installation

Is it possible to run an installer from the MSI that is generated as a solution or is it done from the implemented code?

What I want to do is that the wizard, in addition to installing the files that the implementation already has, run another installer to be able to install another program that the solution needs, in this case it is Microsoft Engine Access (Microsoft Access Runtime).

Is it possible that the wizard itself launches it or do I have to load it by code? Any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: Your stated question - the first sentence - isn't entirely clear to me, but [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), a free installation package builder, uses a scripting language that allows you to check for things that are installed, download additional components, and do all sorts of things.

Comment: iirc the deployment project includes the ability to include prerequisites